# Grails domain not persisting even with flush: true parameters

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am having difficulty in inserting a new record using Grails `domain` class:

```
Integer lastId = AdjustmentCode.createCriteria().get {
    projections { max "id" }
} as Integer

def adjustmentCode = new AdjustmentCode()
adjustmentCode.setId(String.valueOf(lastId + 1))
adjustmentCode.setDescription(description)
adjustmentCode.setType(type)
adjustmentCode.setStatus(status)

println "before saving"
def status_e = adjustmentCode.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

println "status_e: $status_e"
if(!status_e) { println adjustmentCode.errors.allErrors() }

println "after saving"
```

The console displays:

```
before saving
status_e: AdjustmentCode : 14
after saving
```

There is nothing wrong with `adjustmentCode.save(flash: true, failOnError: true)`, I had provided all the `required` (and all the `nullable` ones too). And it doesn't returns any `error` messages, nor reaches the `println adjustmentCode.errors.allErrors()` line. What seems to be the error why it does not save?

---

**EDIT 1:** Because of [zoran119](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055165/zoran119) advise to enable the `sql logging`, I've found out that the `.save()` function generates an `update` statement, not an `insert` one. Now I explicitly tell the `.save ()` function that it should create an `insert` sql statement by using the `insert` params:

```
def status_e = adjustmentCode.save(flush: true, failOnError: true, insert: true)
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But still it performs an `update` query! What should I do to make it create an `insert` statement?

Comment: o.O Why are you assigning your own Id like that? Why not let Hibernate handle that for you? It would also be helpful for you to include the code around (e.g. service method implementation) the saving of your domain class.

Comment: Because the `ID` is of type `String` since there are times user lets the computer to decide (in which the computer get the greatest all-numeric `ID` e.g. `0081795` _plus_ `1`), or provide his own `ID` (which most of the case becomes _alphanumeric_ e.g. `ag23d9b16`

Comment: Then you have a lot of other issues with the above code other than it simply not saving. Good luck!

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Though the compiler printed `status_e: AdjustmentCode : 14` which means the `domain` class is saved, but not `persisted` against the database. Because I've red that `.save()` returns `null` if unseccessful and returns the `domain` object if otherwise. So I thought it saved.

Comment: turn on sql logging and see if there is anything helpful there

Comment: @zoran119 Thanks to your tip, please see my edit.

Comment: If you want to implement something like this with your custom id implementation, you should do this in another attribute. `id` is and should be a technical thing, that should not be touched by users. Take a look at the [grails sequence number generator  plugin](https://github.com/goeh/grails-sequence-generator) for logical identifiers...

Comment: grails-sequence-generator plugin it's a great plugin and I heavily used it in my system. You should take a look at it.

Comment: @MarioDavid So... does that mean that the grails `domain` class cannot use a user-defined `ID` and must be always a _sequencial_ integer type?

Comment: nope, thats not what i meant. I said, that you should avoid doing something like this (as @JoshaMoore said). In fact you can. Just use `generator: 'assigned'` of the id attribute (see the [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)). But your example above shows some serious problems. Like not thread safe, or what happens with your lastId + 1 if as you described a user puts an id like `ag23d9b16` ?

Comment: @MarioDavid There are *omitted* lines above that contains nested `if-else` statements (I've just omitted them for simplicity)... Anyway, since it is unsafe, should I create a new property for my `domain` class or on the `database` as well? Can it also solve the problem about `update` statement are generated instead of `insert` statements? We are not allowed to do `DDL` scripts on the database...

Comment: in both cases: using `generator: 'assigned'` as well as using a logical identifier colum should do the trick, with `update / insert` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are manually setting the id -- this is a little dangerous, as it means you will perform an `update` rather than an `insert` if the id already exists (assuming unique/primary keys).  Try letting the database handle id generation and you should be OK.